# Remove the "Access steam community while playing" message?

Tags: steam

I want to keep the shift+tab overlay and all other toast messages but I want to remove the initial "Access steam community while playing" message. It gets in the menu sometimes.

Comment: Don't think this is possible. You could try reskinning Steam, but that won't help since the region where it's meant to appear will still be blocked by the  pop-up (even if it's invisible).

Answer (score 5):

You can do this on a per-game basis, by right-clicking the game, selecting Properties and unchecking the "Enable Steam Community In-game". This disables the whole Overlay for the game.

Disabling the message only is not possible.

Comment: That will just disable the overlay completely, which is explicitly not wanted. OP just wants to remove the first toast, which reminds you of the existence of the overlay.

Answer (score 1):

"You can disable it from the settings>in-game. There's an option called "enable steam community in-game" uncheck that one.

You can also do this on a per-game basis, by right-clicking the game, selecting Properties and unchecking the "Enable Steam Community In-game"."

Comment: Will this disable the steam overlay?